# How to change ubuntu one windows location

Tags: ubuntu-one-windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I sync a folder from another partition/drive on Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64079/why-cant-i-sync-a-folder-from-another-partition-drive-on-windows)

My **C drive** is full and ubuntu one is taking a lot of space
Can I change the default location of Ubuntu One folder on windows from c drive to d drive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving your ubuntu one folder to the D drive then run this command in cmd

```
mklink /D C:\path\to\where\ubuntuone\expects\folder D:\path\to\where\folder\really\is
```

That should make a symbolic link to the ubuntu one folder. As I side note, this is also how I move my steam games to separate partitions.